# Check if an employee email contains his name - not a case sensitive

Tags: mysql, select, join

I would like to display the name and the email associated with it when the employee name is contained within the email. A user can have more than one email.

```
employee
id   name 
1    Steve Been
2    Rob Kem
3    Bob Kimi
```

---

```
Emails
emplyee_id email
1          steve@domain.com
1          007@domain.com
1          Been@domain.com
2          Robkem@domain.com 
2          Rob.Kem@domain.com 
3          Boooob@domain.com
3          kimi@domain.com
```

---

**The query should not be case sensitive.** I would like this query to show me something like:

```
name            email
Steve Been      steve@domain.com
Steve Been      Been@domain.com
Rob Kem         Robkem@domain.com 
Rob Kem         Rob.Kem@domain.com       
Bob Kimi        kimi@domain.com
```

---

I tried this but I got empty output:

```
select empl.Name as 'employee Name', em.email as 'Product Name'

from email em JOIN employee empl
ON em.employee_id = empl.ID

WHERE FIND_IN_SET(LOWER(empl.Name),LOWER(em.Name))
```

Comment: first you need to break out the tokens (first and last name, as well as items before the @ and between the '.') then you need to compare each of those to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT e.name,
       m.email
  FROM emails m JOIN
       employee e ON m.emplyee_id = e.id
 WHERE INSTR(m.email, SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.name, ' ', 1)) > 0 
    OR INSTR(m.email, SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.name, ' ', -1)) > 0
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/763ab2/8)**

*`INSTR()` is case insensitive unless one of the stings is a binary string, but you can always add `LOWER()` for a good measure.*

UPDATE: As per your additional request you can do that with a query like this

```
SELECT name, 
       total, 
       matched, 
       total - matched unmatched
  FROM (
SELECT e.name,
       COUNT(*) total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN INSTR(m.email, SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.name, ' ', 1)) > 0 
                  OR INSTR(m.email, SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.name, ' ', -1)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) matched
  FROM emails m JOIN
       employee e ON m.emplyee_id = e.id
 GROUP BY e.id, e.name) q
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/763ab2/20)**

Comment: works like pro!!! thanks a lot Peterm! and the demo was an awesome move!!!! again thank you very much!!!!

Comment: Hi Peterm, I would like to ask you for a favor, can I get the name of the employee and the count of how many emails match and how many are not? thank you in advance!

Comment: @mongotop Such a question is worth additional post. Anyway see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, and b/c your query I had to change so many queries on the tools I built! thousand percent much better the `LIKE` function